# Undefined name 'id'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-maps

I am getting the above error in my project. I am creating a toiler finder application based on flutter.
I am using the https://github.com/budipest/mobile?ref=flutterawesome.com project as a reference.
I am not getting how id is giving me error here
Please help me out with it as soon as possible

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/Toilet.dart';

class API {
  static http.Client _client;
  static final _url = "https://budipest-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1";
  static final _defaultHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  };

  static void init() {
    _client = http.Client();
  }

  static Future<List<Toilet>> getToilets() async {
    final response = await _client.get(Uri.parse('$_url/toilets'));
    final body = json.decode(response.body)["data"];

    return body
        .map<Toilet>((toiletRaw) => Toilet.fromMap(Map.from(toiletRaw)))
        .toList();
  }

  static Future<Toilet> getToilet(String id) async {
    final response = await _client.get(Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/$id'));
    final body = json.decode(response.body);

    return Toilet.fromMap(body);
  }

  static Future<Toilet> addToilet(Toilet toilet) async {
    final response = await _client.post(
      Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/$id'),
      headers: _defaultHeaders,
      body: utf8.encode(json.encode(toilet.toJson())),
    );

    final body = json.decode(response.body)["toilet"];

    return Toilet.fromMap(body);
  }

  static Future<Toilet> voteToilet(
    String toiletId,
    String userId,
    int vote,
  ) async {
    final response = await _client.post(
      Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/$toiletId/votes/$userId'),
      headers: _defaultHeaders,
      body: utf8.encode(json.encode({"vote": vote})),
    );

    final body = json.decode(response.body)["toilet"];

    return Toilet.fromMap(body);
  }

  static Future<Toilet> addNote(
    String toiletId,
    String userId,
    String note,
  ) async {
    final response = await _client.post(
      Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/$toiletId/notes/$userId'),
      headers: _defaultHeaders,
      body: utf8.encode(json.encode({"note": note})),
    );

    final body = json.decode(response.body)["toilet"];

    return Toilet.fromMap(body);
  }

  static Future<Toilet> removeNote(String toiletId, String userId) async {
    final response = await _client.delete(
      Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/$toiletId/notes/$userId'),
      headers: _defaultHeaders,
    );

    final body = json.decode(response.body)["toilet"];

    return Toilet.fromMap(body);
  }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: In the future, please [edit] your question and show the exact error message or traces you are getting and show what debugging steps you've taken. However, look closely at where you copied and pasted the `addToilet()` method. Look _very_ closely at that method. Hint: the error message or traces would have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

your `addToilet` tries to use a variable `id` at

```
Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/$id'),
```

But you don't have access to any id there. The reference project also doesn't have it.

So either change that to just

```
Uri.parse('$_url/toilets/'),
```

or something, or provide it as parameter like

```
static Future<Toilet> addToilet(Toilet toilet, String id) async {
```